# How can I make Data Flow column mapping Dynamic in Azure Data Factory based on different column names of Source and target?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have to make columns mapping in Data flow of the Azure Data factory dynamic, so that I can copy data from source to target with varying column names.

Note: Do not require dynamic column mapping method.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your source and sink column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `Rule-base mapping` in **Select transformation** to add a dynamic column to the output.

Below are my repro details with sample data.

1. Connect the source to the source dataset in data flow activity. Here **source** **column** ‘*StateProvinceID*’ has a different name compared to my sink. In **sink** my the **column** name to store the value of *StateProvinceID* is ‘***StateId***’.

**Source preview:**

[image]

2. Add `select` transformation to the source output.
3. In **Select settings**, add Rule-based mapping to write a **dynamic expression** to match the column name with the sink column.

[image]

4. Write the below **expression** to identify the source column name and give the sink column name under **Name as**.

`type=='string' && locate('state', lower(name)) == 1`

[image]

**The output of Select:**

[image]

Comment: Rule based mapping is for the same column names available in Source table as well as in target table. what if the source and target tables have different column name

Comment: We can also use Alter Row transformation in data flow, for dynamic Upsert of the data between Source to Target with same column name.